# TRANSACTION_REFUSED - The transaction was refused. in paypal ios sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal

I am using following code in appdelegate

```
[PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:@{PayPalEnvironmentProduction : @"some client id"}];
```

And using this code for paypalpayment

```
#define kPayPalEnvironment PayPalEnvironmentProduction


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set up payPalConfig
    _payPalConfig = [[PayPalConfiguration alloc] init];
    _payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = YES;
    _payPalConfig.languageOrLocale = @"en";
    _payPalConfig.merchantName = @"Anything";

    _payPalConfig.languageOrLocale = [NSLocale preferredLanguages][0];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // use default environment, should be Production in real life
    self.environment = kPayPalEnvironment;

    NSLog(@"PayPal iOS SDK version: %@", [PayPalMobile libraryVersion]);
}

- (IBAction)btnPaypalClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
    PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
    payment.amount = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"5"];
    payment.currencyCode = @"GBP";
    payment.shortDescription = @"anything";


    if (!payment.processable) {
        // This particular payment will always be processable. If, for
        // example, the amount was negative or the shortDescription was
        // empty, this payment wouldn't be processable, and you'd want
        // to handle that here.
    }

    // Update payPalConfig re accepting credit cards.
    self.payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = self.acceptCreditCards;

    PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithPayment:payment
                                                                                                configuration:self.payPalConfig
                                                                                                     delegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (void)payPalPaymentViewController:(PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController didCompletePayment:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment
{
    NSLog(@"PayPal Payment Success!");
    NSLog(@"%@",completedPayment);

    [self saveCompletedPayment:completedPayment]; // Payment was processed successfully; send to server for verification and fulfillment
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I am using all above codes for paypal payment.
but when i pay it shows following error

TRANSACTION_REFUSED - The transaction was refused.

I have balance in my paypal account but still getting this error.

Is there anything still i am missing.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please see discussion at https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/111 The reason for decline is Unfortunately the payment couldn't be completed with the funding source chosen. Please attempt with a different funding option.